# Trying to make quit sequence that only proceeds when correct input is given

Tags: c#

i'm having trouble creating a loop that will request user input and if the input is not "Y" or "N" to re-prompt the user to input over and over until they give the correct input.

```
while (quitOrContinue != "Y"|"N")//cant use "Y"/"N" in the same line, how do I phrase this line?
Console.Write("\nWould you like to process another set of bowling scores?");
Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'Y' to process another set or 'N' to exit the program");

Console.Clear();// this needs to happen if the input to run again is "Y"
```

Comment: I don't see any loop code in your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for starters, you're not actually taking any input at all from the user. You can use Console.WriteLine to output whatever sort of instructions you want from the user, but you have to actually capture them somehow.

To get input, you'd have to use `Console.Read()`, and you'd have to use conditional blocks to check their input. You should wrap your code in a while loop that references a sentinel value:

```
bool userIsDone = false;
Console.Write("\nWould you like to process...");
while (!userIsDone)
{
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    // ...
    if (userInput == "Y")
    {
        // process another set here
        Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to process...");
    }
    else if (userInput == "N")
    {
        // exit your program
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That input is invalid.");
    }
}
```

Also, about the code you have above - you should wrap the elements inside loops in { }, and the | is the bitwise OR, not logical or. Logical or (which I'm 99% you want in this situation) is ||, and logical and is &&.

Comment: Console.Read returns an int

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah, I'm editing that now, along with a couple other things.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a loop ?

```
string input = null;
while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "Y" || input != "N")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, please try again:");
}
```

Here the expression `(input = Console.ReadLine()) != "Y" || input != "N"` will be evaluated before and each time after the loop runs. It basically reads a line from the input stream and assign it to input variable then checks if it's not `Y` or `N` it executes the loop body and evaluates the expression again and ask for input until the condition satisfies.You can use `Console.Read` method to read one charachter but it returns `int` so you need to cast it to `char`.

Comment: When I do this the program does not exit, if i use the if/else below it still does not quit. How can I make it quit when N is inputted, or loop back to the top when Y is inputted

Comment: After loop, check the value of input!